# Does MailApp.sendEmail() method impersonate sender address?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I'm sending mail to a third party-service from Gmail using Google Apps Script. This third party requires the sender email address be registered with them. If the sender is not registered, an error/marketing message is sent back to the original sender.

When the message is sent from Gmail manually, it is processed as expected by the third party. When the message is sent by a script, the message is not processed by the third party and no error response is sent as described above. After adding a different gmail address as a BCC on one such message, I found the script generated message shows "mailed-by: bounce.secureserver.net" and "signed-by: gmail.com"

I'm worried GAS is impersonating the sender in such a way that the third party does not recognize the sender as a registered address. Or, the third party may be dropping the messages as spam. (http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/tGxlioK1ejg/discussion)

Community feedback on this problem is most appreciated.

Comment: Do you use MailApp or GmailApp ?

Comment: @Serge you get the same effect ( via maestro.bounces.google.com )  on both GMAILApp and MailApp sendEmail()

Comment: right ;-) just checked... I'm surprised by the issues you get, I use this feature a lot but never had this filtering issue... couldn't you ask the recipient's service to register the adress with the 'via maestro.bounces...' ? Actually I didn't care about that since I use thunderbird to read mails and it hides this part of the sender ID...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google's documentation, the [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail) method sends an email as the user running the script. That being said, additional parameters are automatically added to the email's header, and these might trigger some filtering rules on the recipient side. There is not much you can do about that, beside using a third-party email service like SendGrid which might do a better job at ensuring that your email will go through.

Comment: true, but the using the sendEmail() method will automatically trigger the "sent by third party" condition which can then be filtered quite reasonably by the destination that is relying on an authenticated address. You can see this effect on incoming mail to gmail and g-apps accounts. SPF may be the answer - see the end of this article http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1311182&authuser=1

Comment: Instead of using mail, I had to switch a different vendor and call their restAPI using URLfetch() to overcome this problem.